# Node module's dependencies will not update after update or install?

Tags: node.js, npm, highcharts

I want to use `react-highcharts` in my application. I used `npm install react-highcharts`, which succeeded with the warning:

```
found 1 high severity vulnerability, run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details.
```

`npm audit fix` did nothing; it said I had to manually fix the issue. I ran `npm audit` to see what was going on, and got

```
                       === npm audit security report ===

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Cross-Site Scripting                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ highcharts                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=7.2.2 <8.0.0 || >=8.1.1                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-highcharts                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-highcharts > highcharts                                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1227                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 1 high severity vulnerability in 994 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

The ["More info" link](https://npmjs.com/advisories/1227) and the "Patched in" row reveal that this was fixed in highcharts >=8.1.1. The most recent version is `highcharts@9.0.0`, so I decided to update it:

```
❯ npm update highcharts -dd
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'update',
npm verb cli   'highcharts',
npm verb cli   '-dd'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.10
npm info using node@v14.15.4
npm verb npm-session 0b92b8dc64938cea
npm verb update computing outdated modules to update
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 1507ms
npm info ok
```

"It worked if it ends in ok," but look:

```
❯ npm list highcharts
myproj@1.0.0 /Users/actinidia/myproj
└─┬ react-highcharts@16.1.0
  └── highcharts@6.2.0
```

I still have `highcharts@6.2.0`! And running `npm install highcharts` just leads to a second copy of highcharts, though the new version is indeed version 9.0.0:

```
├── highcharts@9.0.0
└─┬ react-highcharts@16.1.0
  └── highcharts@6.2.0
```

How do I update the dependency that `react-highcharts` will use?

Comment: Hi @actinidia, I recommend you to use the officialy supported wrapper for Highcharts: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall highcharts first and install again.

```
npm uninstall react-highcharts
npm install react-highcharts
```

Comment: This results in two copies of highcharts (9.0.0 and 6.2.0); see the bottom of my post for what I mean.

Comment: Then you should modify package.json file without highcharts and npm install with force command.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [ppotaczek's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66040957/node-modules-dependencies-will-not-update-after-update-or-install/66041477?noredirect=1#comment116765862_66040957) and installed the officialy supported wrapper for Highcharts. It was as easy as

```
❯ npm install highcharts-react-official
npm WARN highcharts-react-official@3.0.0 requires a peer of highcharts@>=6.0.0
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ highcharts-react-official@3.0.0
added 1 package and audited 992 packages in 4.48s

❯ npm install highcharts
+ highcharts@9.0.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 993 packages in 4.978s
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove installed: `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

Modify the `package.json` format as follows

```
npm audit fix --force

npm install
```